# How can I copy the entire (all formats) of the clipboard

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, idataobject

We need to copy and re-post what is in the clipboard - all formats. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the use case. We have small docx/pptx/xlsx documents that, in our Office AddIn, we want to enable the user to drag/drop into word/ppt/xl. Unfortunately, the best documented format for this is html which is not that close to the actual docx/pptx/xlsx.

So, my thought is we (using Word as the example) create an instance of a Word Document object (our code is a Word AddIn so by definition Word is running). We then call that Document object to select all of it and then paste the selection.

At this point the clipboard contains that pasted document. Including in the undocumented format Word uses for copy/paste within Word documents. That's the format we want to use.

If we can then copy all of the clipboard contents into an object of ours that implements IDataObject and pass that object to Control.DoDragDrop(), then when the user drops it somewhere in Word, they are giving it to Word in the undocumented format which has all the docx formatting.

Is there a way to do this?

**Update:** We need to drag/drop the file contents (not just the text, the fully formatted text, tables, shapes, charts, etc.).

**Update 2:** We need to pass this as an IDataObject to DoDragDrop(), not do a paste from the clipboard. We do **not** need to be notified when it happens because we've passed the IDataObject to Windows and Windows takes it from there.

Comment: "We have small docx/pptx/xlsx documents that, in our Office AddIn, we want to enable the user to drag/drop into word/ppt/xl" -- Just to clarify, you want to be able to paste the document *text* (and formatting) into those programs? Or do you want to allow them to drag the document *file* into those programs?

Comment: So this can 100% be done. But some limitations. If you are going to work on the assumption that when your code runs the proper text is in the clipboard then you can use the clipboard classes. If you need to be notified of text being copied to the clipboard you are going to need to figure out delayed rendering of clipboard data which is troublesome.

Comment: @Quantic - the contents (text, tables, shapes, etc.)

Comment: @Jacobr365 - We need it in an IDataObject we pass to DoDragDrop() and  DoDragDrop() ignores the clipboard. But the content would remain in the clipboard too.

Comment: `IDataObject` is the format used by the `Clipboard` class. Check remarks https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idataobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sounds like you want the user to be able to drag File1, drop it onto a document, then at that point, insert the contents of File1 into the document at that point. Is that right?

Comment: @Ben - yes exactly.

Comment: can't u make a backup of the document then open the backup and run the copy command when needed? this way you don't need to poke around undocumented clipoard formats。

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 - we're trying to be user friendly. Also, running all that with automated macros in Office is a recipe for disaster as oftentimes something will go wrong.

Comment: OK so first part is: Function to open file, select and copy contents, and paste to current location. Then get that working with file/open dialog. When that works you can worry about drag& drop - dropping a file gives you the path, so the previous method can be reused whole.

Comment: @Ben I think that approach would be very user unfriendly. I prefer what I'm trying to do as it then all happens invisibly to the user and is performing the drag/drop in the way Windows expects (so less chance of errors do to doing something squirrelly).

Comment: @DavidThielen I understand that. Here's the thing: Dragging and Dropping files only drops the file paths to the receiving application. So your job is in two parts: Part 1) Given the file path, insert the contents into the document. Part 2) Given a dropped file, extract the file name and trigger Part 1.

Comment: @Ben - No, that's why I'm asking about creating an IDataObject from the paste of the document contents. That will give me a drop object that is the document contents, not the filename.

Comment: Dragging files does not create an IDataObject which contains the file contents, it creates an IDataObject which contains the file paths. This is controlled by the application in which the Drag operation **commences**, which is Explorer, no?

Comment: @Ben I am not dragging a file. I am dragging an object in my application which represents the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a call for this - Clipboard.GetDataObject().